# PHP 7.2 Function create_function() is deprecated

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

I have used `create_function()` in my application below.

```php
$callbacks[$delimiter] = create_function(
  '$matches',
   "return '$delimiter' . strtolower(\$matches[1]);"
);
```

But for PHP 7.2.0, `create_function()` is deprecated.

How do I rewrite my code above for PHP 7.2.0?

Comment: you may create an anonymous function if that solves the issue

Comment: Can we see your larger `preg_` code block?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You should be able to use an [Anonymous Function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (aka Closure) with a call to the parent scoped `$delimiter` variable, like so:

```
$callbacks[$delimiter] = function($matches) use ($delimiter) {
    return $delimiter . strtolower($matches[1]);
};
```

Answer (score 117):

I would like to contribute with a very simple case I found in a Wordpress Theme and seems to work properly:

Having the following **add_filter** statement:

```php
add_filter(
  'option_page_capability_' . ot_options_id(),
  create_function( '$caps', "return '$caps';" ),
  999
);
```

Replace it for:

```php
add_filter(
  'option_page_capability_' . ot_options_id(),
  function($caps) {return $caps;},
  999
);
```

We can see the usage of `function()`, very typical function creation instead of a deprecated `create_function()` to create functions.

Comment: what actually is a anonymos function (closure) and was already posted by @e_i_pi :)

Comment: @Dwza Yep, only I was to extend a bit more this topic. Nothing more.

Comment: I was very helpful to see an example. Thanks @Joanmacat!

Comment: Because I was looking for a WordPress-specific fix, I liked your example. It's always good to have _additional_ use-cases, even if there already was an approved answer...

Answer (score 10):

## Automated Upgrade

If anyone needs to upgrade dozens of `create_function()` cases in their code to anonymous functions, I work on a tool called [Rector](http://github.com/rectorphp/rector).

It goes through the code and replaces the `create_function` with anonymous functions 1:1. It's tested on [30 various cases](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/12/17/function-create-function-is-deprecated-in-php-72-how-to-migrate/).

**Install**

```
composer require rector/rector --dev
```

**Setup**

Let's say you want to upgrade code in the `/src` directory.

```
# rector.php
<?php

use Rector\Core\Configuration\Option;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator\ContainerConfigurator;
use Rector\Php72\Rector\FuncCall\CreateFunctionToAnonymousFunctionRector;

return static function (ContainerConfigurator $containerConfigurator) {
    $parameters = $containerConfigurator->parameters();
    $parameters->set(Option::PATHS, [
        __DIR__ . '/src',
    ]);

    $services = $containerConfigurator->services();
    $services->set(CreateFunctionToAnonymousFunctionRector::class);
};
```

**Run on your code**

```
# this is set run, it only report what it would change
vendor/bin/rector process --config rector.php --dry-run

# this actually changes the code
vendor/bin/rector process --config rector.php

# the "rector.php" config is loaded by default, so we can drop it
vendor/bin/rector process
```

---

**EDIT:** Updated 2020-10-31 with PHP Rector 0.8.x syntax

Comment: Not sure why this isn't working.  It may need more information, or there has been a change.  I created the yml file, but it always says cannot load resource.  When I use the php file, things work fine though.

Comment: Oh, the yml file is deprecated for coupled of months. I'll update this post, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: It may be good to clarify that "src" on the command line, and '/src' in the file need to be changed to match the user's path.  That is something lacking in the documentation too.  It just assumes that people know what to do with it, or that it's there to be changed in the first place.

Comment: Good point. I'll update the answer here. Could you help me and send send PR to documentation README on GitHub?

Comment: I tested this out on a some old WordPress plugins that are going to die when PHP is upgraded to 8.x.  It totally worked!  Here's a link to the repo with the latest code: https://github.com/rectorphp/rector

Answer (score 3):

Since PHP 7.4 you can use an [Arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php):

```
$callbacks[$delimiter] = fn($matches) => $delimiter . strtolower($matches[1]);
```

Arrow functions are shorter than anonymous functions, and use the parent scope - so you can refer to $delimiter without passing it in.

Comment: As an aside, I see this exact line of code in the Braintree lib used by MachForm, in a snippet that IMO should not be using create_function anyways (for garbage-collection reasons). Coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

This Array of Anonymous functions worked for me, see code below:

```
// This will be a dynamic name that could 
// be used as a function like "namespace".
$dynamic_name = 'my_dynamic_name';

// Here's some variables that you could use in the scope of
// your dynamic anonymous functions. 
$outerVariable = 'If I need this varible, I can use it';
$outerVariableTwo = 'If I need this varible, I can use it too!';

// Create an array that we can later use and turn into 
// and associative array with our new dynamic anonymous functions.
$dynamicAnonFunctions = [];

// Create the first dynamic function.
$dynamicAnonFunctions[($dynamic_name."_func_one")] = function () use ($outerVariable, $dynamic_name) { 
    echo 'Running: function <b>'.$dynamic_name .'_func_one()</b>';
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo $outerVariable;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo 'This works :)'; 
    echo '<br><br>';
};

// Create the second dynamic function 
$dynamicAnonFunctions[($dynamic_name."_func_two")] = function () use ($outerVariableTwo, $dynamic_name) { 
    echo '- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ';
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo 'Running: function <b>'.$dynamic_name .'_func_two()</b>';
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo $outerVariableTwo;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo 'This also works :)!'; 
    echo '<br><br>';
};

// Call the functions.
$dynamicAnonFunctions[($dynamic_name."_func_one")]();
$dynamicAnonFunctions[($dynamic_name."_func_two")]();

// Halt execution.
exit();
```

Just copy this into your script file and you will see the output from the `echo` statements, then simply remap the function to your own will!

Happy coding =)

Answer (score -2):

The anonymous function solution works, but if the expression to be returned is in a string I think `eval` should be used.

```
$callbacks[$delimiter] = eval('return function($matches){return '.$delimiter.' . strtolower($matches[1]);};');
```