# Replace create_function with anonymous function

Tags: php, anonymous-function, php-7.2, create-function

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161526/php-7-2-function-create-function-is-deprecated) before posting the question.

this is a small part of a code that uses `create_function`

```
$lambda_functions[$code_hash] = create_function('$action, &$self, $text', 'if ($action == "encrypt") { '.$encrypt.' } else { '.$decrypt.' }');
```

tried using this way

```
$lambda_functions[$code_hash] = function ( $action, &$self, $text ) use ( $encrypt, $decrypt ) {
                if ($action == "encrypt") {
                    return $encrypt;
                } else {
                    return $decrypt;
                }
            };
```

but doesn't work as expected `$encrypt` or `$decrypt` will contain code that looks something like this

```
$encrypt = $init_encryptBlock . '
           $ciphertext = "";
           $text = $self->_pad($text);
           $plaintext_len = strlen($text);

           $in = $self->encryptIV;

             for ($i = 0; $i < $plaintext_len; $i+= '.$block_size.') {
              $in = substr($text, $i, '.$block_size.') ^ $in;
                        '.$_encryptBlock.'
                        $ciphertext.= $in;
             }

             if ($self->continuousBuffer) {
               $self->encryptIV = $in;
             }

             return $ciphertext;
             ';
```

It is working fine with `create_function` but not with `anonymous` function not sure where I am going wrong?

Comment: have you tried to check the value returned by the lambda code you created? you are assigning string to $encrypt you should use eval function before submitting it to the lambda function like @philipp said create_function is evaluating the strings as php function.

Comment: @ChristopherPelayo thanks for your  input, the output of `create_function` is `�lambda_1` also i need a way without using `eval` or  `create_function` 'coz of the caution [here](@ChristopherPelayo thanks for your  input, the output of `create_function` is `�lambda_1` also i need a way without using `eval` or  `create_function` 'coz of the [caution](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is, that with `create_function()` your code was submitted as a string and interpreted as code, but with an anonymous function the string is interpreted as a string, not as the code it contains.

You can just extract the code you have from the string that you have in `$encrypt` and `$decrypt`. This would look like this:

```
/*
 * Removed the "use ($encrypt, $decrypt)" part, 
 * because those were the strings that contained the code, 
 * but now the code itself is part of the anonymous function.
 * 
 * Instead, i added "use ($block_size)", because this is a vairable,
 * which is not defined inside of your function, but still used in it.
 * The other code containing variables might include such variables as
 * well, which you need to provide in the use block, too.
 */
$lambda_functions[$code_hash] = function ( $action, &$self, $text ) use ($block_size) {
    if ($action == "encrypt") {
        //Extract $init_encryptBlock here
        $ciphertext = "";
        $text = $self->_pad($text);
        $plaintext_len = strlen($text);

        $in = $self->encryptIV;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $plaintext_len; $i+= $block_size) {
            $in = substr($text, $i, $block_size) ^ $in;
            // Extract $_encryptBlock here
            $ciphertext.= $in;
        }

        if ($self->continuousBuffer) {
            $self->encryptIV = $in;
        }

         return $ciphertext;
    } else {
        //Extract $decrypt here
    }
};
```

Please keep in mind, that this is not a complete answer. You find numerous `// Extract $variable here` comments in the code, which stand for each code containing variable, that you have in your code and which needs to be extracted just in the way, in which i etracted the code from `$encrypt`.

Comment: thanks for your time, I will check by adding the extracted code.