# Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated PHP 7.2

Tags: function, deprecated, create-function

```
add_filter( 'option_page_capability_' . ot_options_id(), create_function( '$caps', "return '$caps';" ), 999 );
```

How to write this correctly so that there is no error:

> Deprecated: Function `create_function()` is deprecated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 7.2 Function create\_function() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161526/php-7-2-function-create-function-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an anonymous function:

```
add_filter( 'option_page_capability_' . ot_options_id(), function($caps) {return $caps;}, 999 );
```

Keep in mind that this will have different functionality to your code, as your code substitutes `$caps` in function definition, which is buggy and asking for a code injection.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ';' in  (((

Comment: Try now; I added the semicolon.

Comment: Could you accept my edit to your question? Also, if this solved your problem, please accept this answer by clicking the grey check mark to turn it green.