# How to Update Braintree payment dependency in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, braintree-sandbox

I am working with Laravel 5.6 and using Braintree payment gateway sand box. but when I update my php version it is encounters some error. like this

```
Function create_function() is deprecated
in Util.php line 206
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8192, 'Function create_function() is deprecated', 'C:\\Users\\mala\\Desktop\\ddddd\\vendor\\braintree\\braintree_php\\lib\\Braintree\\Util.php', 206, array('string' => 'client_token', 'delimiter' => '-', 'callbacks' => array()))in Util.php line 206
```

so, I am using braintree vertion,
```
"oureastudios/laravel5-braintree": "dev-master"
``
but when I search in internet most people suggested update braintree dependancy to v3.26.0. then My problem is how can I update My current braintree to above new vertion?

Comment: you have to check for the braintree sdk along with the composer on the laravel directory or project directory. You need check for the update as per the laravel version

Comment: actually I do not need update laravel version only new braintree version

Comment: We also need to check the supported version for the braintree, that the new version is supportable to the current laravel version or not.

Comment: No, any solutions here

Comment: There is might help [Function create_function() is Deprecated in PHP 7.2 - How to Migrate?](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/12/17/function-create-function-is-deprecated-in-php-72-how-to-migrate/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 7.2 Function create\_function() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161526/php-7-2-function-create-function-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

create_function is deprecated in PHP 7.2

in the file /Braintree/Util.php
the function delimiterToCamelCase

Use:

```
$callback = function ($matches) {
                return strtoupper($matches[1]);
            };
```

instead of:

```
$callback = create_function('$matches', 'return strtoupper($matches[1]);');
```

Link Reference:
https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/commit/37e54736ef949cc022a3f87a9fed53820b798c3e