# create_function() deprecated. WordPress settings page error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function for the WordPress settings where the `create_function()` was used but when I updated the server to PHP7.2, and it says the function is deprecated.

I don't know what alternative to use.

**Code**

```php
if ( isset( $section['desc'] ) && ! empty( $section['desc'] ) ) {
  $section['desc'] = '<div class="inside">' . $section['desc'] . '</div>';
  $callback = create_function( '', 'echo "' . str_replace( '"', '\"', $section['desc'] ) . '";' );
} elseif ( isset( $section['callback'] ) ) {
  $callback = $section['callback'];
} else {
  $callback = null;
}
```

Comment: There is might help [Function create_function() is Deprecated in PHP 7.2 - How to Migrate?](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/12/17/function-create-function-is-deprecated-in-php-72-how-to-migrate/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 7.2 Function create\_function() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161526/php-7-2-function-create-function-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create an anonymous function to use as a callback:

Your line:

```
$callback = create_function( '', 'echo "' . str_replace( '"', '\"', $section['desc'] ) . '";' );
```

Could be replaced with:

```
$callback = function() use($section) { echo str_replace ('"', '\"', $section['desc']); };
```