# PHP 7.2 create_function() deprecated

Tags: php, php-7.2

I have a function which I'm not entirely sure how to convert to get it working with PHP 7.2:

```
static function toCamelCaseFromUnderscore($str) {
    $func = create_function('$c', 'return strtoupper($c[1]);');
    return preg_replace_callback('/_([a-z])/', $func, $str);
}
```

Comment: There are many examples in the doc. Can you please post what you tried as well as the error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 7.2 Function create\_function() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161526/php-7-2-function-create-function-is-deprecated)

Comment: There is might help [Function create_function() is Deprecated in PHP 7.2 - How to Migrate?](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/12/17/function-create-function-is-deprecated-in-php-72-how-to-migrate/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I agree with the comments, the examples on PHP.net are more then clear, for sake of closing this

```
static function toCamelCaseFromUnderscore($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/_([a-z])/', function($c){
         return strtoupper($c[1]);
    }, $str);
}
```