# Migration from depricated function create_function

Tags: php

I have function in my script but after updating my php version to 7.3 i receive an notice that function create_function is deprecated. How can i migrate and what can i use instead of create_function?

```
function rc4($key, $data){
    // Store the vectors "S" has calculated
    static $SC;
    // Function to swaps values of the vector "S"
    $swap = create_function('&$v1, &$v2', '
        $v1 = $v1 ^ $v2;
        $v2 = $v1 ^ $v2;
        $v1 = $v1 ^ $v2;
    ');
    $ikey = crc32($key);
    if (!isset($SC[$ikey])) {
        // Make the vector "S", basead in the key
        $S    = range(0, 255);
        $j    = 0;
        $n    = strlen($key);
        for ($i = 0; $i < 255; $i++) {
            $char  = ord($key{$i % $n});
            $j     = ($j + $S[$i] + $char) % 256;
            $swap($S[$i], $S[$j]);
        }
        $SC[$ikey] = $S;
    } else {
        $S = $SC[$ikey];
    }
    // Crypt/decrypt the data
    $n    = strlen($data);
    $data = str_split($data, 1);
    $i    = $j = 0;
    for ($m = 0; $m < $n; $m++) {
        $i        = ($i + 1) % 256;
        $j        = ($j + $S[$i]) % 256;
        $swap($S[$i], $S[$j]);
        $char     = ord($data[$m]);
        $char     = $S[($S[$i] + $S[$j]) % 256] ^ $char;
        $data[$m] = chr($char);
    }
    return $data; implode('', $data);
}
    enter code here
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 7.2 Function create\_function() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161526/php-7-2-function-create-function-is-deprecated)

Comment: And read the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)