# PHP 7.3 Function create_function() is deprecated

Tags: wordpress, php-7.3

I have used create_function in my theme below.

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'register_widget( "Woocommerce_Header_Cart" );' ) );
```

But for PHP 7.3.0, the create_function() is deprecated.

Any idea, how to fix my codes above on PHP 7.3.0.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 7.2 Function create\_function() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161526/php-7-2-function-create-function-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'custom_widget_func');

funcation custom_widget_func(){
    register_widget( "Woocommerce_Header_Cart" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```php
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'register_widget( "Woocommerce_Header_Cart" );' ) );
```

with this, using an anonymous function instead :

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', function() { return register_widget("Woocommerce_Header_Cart"); } );
```