# How upgrade function from create_function to anonymous function

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I need to modify the function so that it doesn't use create_function. I want to use an anonymous feature but I don't know how to use it.

```
function arrayUniqueMerge()
{
    $variables = '$_' . implode(',$_', array_keys(func_get_args()));
    $func = create_function('$tab', ' list(' . $variables . ') = $tab; return array_unique(array_merge(' . $variables . '));');
    return $func(func_get_args());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 7.2 Function create\_function() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161526/php-7-2-function-create-function-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to understand the purpose of your function, but my conclusion was that it is dependant on the PHP version you have build it for.

However, I have come to realize that most likely in PHP 7 your function can be refactored to just the following:

```
function arrayUniqueMerge2(...$args) {
    return array_unique(array_merge(...$args));
}
```

Testing it with the sample data:

```
print_r(arrayUniqueMerge2(['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'd']));
//Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [3] => c [5] => d )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can created anonymous function as such:

```
<?php

$myfunc = function ($x) {
  return $x . ' world';
};

echo $myfunc('Hello'); //Echoes "Hello world"
```

Read more about anonymous functions in the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Also `create_function` was depreaced in PHP `7.2.0`