# Function create_function() is deprecated

Tags: deprecated, php-7.2, create-function

My site is currently on PHP 7.2.0, and I'm getting this error in my debug log showing PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated

I don't know what happened but my site somehow became broken and stuff wasn't showing properly. The only way I can access my wordpress dashboard is when I force the site to load on a default theme.

So I guess the problem lies within my Theme...

Right now, the site doesn't load up at all and it's showing a blank white screen or saying that The site is experiencing technical difficulties.

I'm still a new web developer... Any idea what could have gone wrong and how to fix my current code that is showing the error?

`add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("Essential_Grids_Widget");'));`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 7.2 Function create\_function() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161526/php-7-2-function-create-function-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

```
$MywidgetName='Essential_Grids_Widget';
add_action('widgets_init', function () use ($MywidgetName) {
    return register_widget($MywidgetName);
});
```