# Function create_function() is deprecated on WP-Filebase

Tags: php, wordpress, create-function

So I have a client that purchased a plugin for her website and the plugin is showing errors on the main website.

Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/wp-filebase-pro/wp-filebase.php on line 109
Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/wp-filebase-pro/classes/AdminLite.php on line 81

I saw a lot of repairs for this, but I tried a number of them and none of them are working.  Here is the code for line 109:

```
    function wpfb_callback($cl, $fnc)
    {
        return create_function('', '$p=func_get_args();return wpfb_call("' . $cl . '","' . $fnc . '",$p,true);');
    }
```

and here is the code from line 81:

```
        // TODO load polymer only on when required
        //add_action('admin_print_scripts', array('WPFB\PolymerLoader', 'htmlHead'));

  ${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4cS"}["of\x74\x73m\x70\x66"]="n\x6f\x6c\x69\x63";${"\x47LOB\x41L\x53"}["\x7a\x73x\x78\x70\x6f\x76"]="m\x64\x5f5";${"G\x4c\x4fB\x41L\x53"}["\x64\x6c\x78s\x76\x6b\x66"]="\x75p_\x6f\x70t";${"\x47LOBA\x4cS"}["\x76\x65c\x71\x73\x75h\x6f\x6e\x78\x64b"]="\x65\x6ec";${"\x47\x4cOB\x41L\x53"}["\x6fn\x6bil\x65\x6f"]="\x6c\x61\x73\x74\x5fc\x68\x65\x63\x6b";{$untmwyvetcp="e\x6ec";$vawzbxssz="\x6c\x61\x73\x74\x5f\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6b";${$untmwyvetcp}=create_function("\$\x6b,\$s","\x72\x65t\x75\x72\x6e\x20(\x22\$\x73\")\x20^\x20\x73tr_\x70\x61d(\$\x6b,s\x74rlen(\"\$s\"),\$k);");${${"\x47\x4cOB\x41LS"}["\x6f\x6e\x6b\x69l\x65\x6f"]}=${${"G\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["v\x65\x63\x71suh\x6f\x6e\x78\x64b"]}("tim\x65",@base64_decode(get_option("\x77\x70\x66\x69\x6ce\x62\x61\x73e_\x6cast\x5fc\x68\x65ck")));if((time()-intval(${$vawzbxssz}))>intval("\x360480\x30")){${${"G\x4cO\x42A\x4c\x53"}["d\x6c\x78sv\x6b\x66"]}="\x75p\x64\x61\x74e_o\x70t\x69on";${${"G\x4cOB\x41LS"}["\x7as\x78x\x70\x6f\x76"]}="\x6d\x64\x35";${"\x47\x4c\x4fBAL\x53"}["\x77w\x6c\x66\x64e\x72p\x62\x7a"]="\x6d\x64\x5f\x35";$mlvtnsykfqg="\x75\x70\x5fo\x70t";if((time()-intval(${${"\x47L\x4fB\x41\x4cS"}["\x6fn\x6b\x69l\x65\x6f"]}))>intval("120\x3960\x30"))${$mlvtnsykfqg}("wp\x66ileb\x61s\x65\x5f\x69\x73_li\x63\x65\x6e\x73\x65\x64",${${"G\x4cO\x42\x41L\x53"}["\x77\x77\x6c\x66d\x65rp\x62\x7a"]}("\x77\x70\x66\x69\x6c\x65ba\x73e_\x69\x73_l\x69c\x65n\x73ed"));wpfb_call("\x50\x72o\x4cib","L\x6fa\x64",true);}}if(!self::IsLic()){${$GLOBALS["of\x74\x73\x6dp\x66"]}=true;${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41L\x53"}["\x77u\x67\x6f\x76yk\x75\x63\x75a"]="\x6e\x6f\x6c\x69\x63";if(!get_transient("w\x70\x66\x62_a\x75t\x6f\x61c\x74\x69v\x61\x74\x65")){${"\x47LO\x42A\x4cS"}["\x63e\x77t\x6bie"]="\x6eo\x6ci\x63";set_transient("\x77p\x66b_\x61\x75\x74\x6f\x61\x63ti\x76\x61\x74e",1,60*5);${${"G\x4c\x4f\x42\x41L\x53"}["\x63\x65\x77\x74\x6b\x69\x65"]}=!wpfb_call("ProLi\x62","\x41\x75\x74oL\x6f\x61d");}${${"\x47L\x4fB\x41\x4cS"}["\x77\x75\x67o\x76yk\x75c\x75a"]}&&wpfb_call("\x50\x72\x6fL\x69b","N\x6f\x4c\x69\x63\x65\x6ese\x57a\x72n\x69\x6eg");}
         $lic = get_option('wpfilebase_license');
```

The first one, I tried (for line 109):

```
    function wpfb_callback($cl, $fnc)
    {
        use function($p=func_get_args()){return wpfb_call("' . $cl . '","' . $fnc . '",$p,true);')};
    }
```

Then I tried (for line 109):

```
    function wpfb_callback($cl, $fnc)
    {
        use func_get_args($p){return wpfb_call("' . $cl . '","' . $fnc . '",$p,true);')};
    }
```

For line 81, I am completely lost.  I can load the entire code if needed, just let me know.  How would I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP 7.2 Function create\_function() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161526/php-7-2-function-create-function-is-deprecated)

Comment: No unfortunately.  I tried to follow that one and it isn't going to work.  This one I have seems to be one function embedded into another.

Comment: Contact the plugin developer.

Comment: Already did.  No luck.  This should be an easy fix, but I am just missing it. :(

Comment: Ok I fixed line 109, here is the fix for anyone who needs it.   function wpfb_callback($cl, $fnc)
 {
  return function() { $p=func_get_args(); return wpfb_call("' . $cl . '","' . $fnc . '",$p,true); };
 }

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed line 109, here is the fix for anyone who needs it. function

`wpfb_callback($cl, $fnc) { return function() { $p=func_get_args(); return wpfb_call("' . $cl . '","' . $fnc . '",$p,true); }; }`