# How to solve "Function create_function() is deprecated" in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, hosting

I have one issue with deploying the Laravel project to the hosting server.
It works well before the deployment, but now I have got the following error.

```
ErrorException in Util.php line 206:
Function create_function() is deprecated
```

This project is based on Laravel version 5.4 and the PHP version of the hosting server is 5.6.3.
And I run the following commands:
    `php artisan config:clear`
    `php artisan cache:clear`
However, it occurs the same error.
I would appreciate that let someone know about the solution.
Thanks.
Xiaoxuan.

Comment: `create_function()` is deprecated in PHP 7.2 so not sure why you would get this message(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161526/php-7-2-function-create-function-is-deprecated)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not going to upgrade the PHP version, I want to use PHP version 5.6.3. Because the Laravel project is developed by PHP version 5.6.3.