# PHP Function create_function() is deprecated , the code cant work in newest PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, create-function

I have a function which im not entirely sure how to convert it to get working in newest php

`$eventSponsor = array_map(create_function('$o', 'return $o["id"];'), $event->sponsors);`

which method should i use in newest php version ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP 7.2 Function create\_function() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161526/php-7-2-function-create-function-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

yeah i was searching and i found this method called anonymous function so the code be like

````
$awe function ($o) {
                return $o["id"];
            };

            $eventSponsor = array_map($awe,$event->sponsors); ```
````