# I am having an error on php has there been a change in the way syntax is done?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code on my php website from a theme i made a long time ago but it gives warnings on 7.4 and errors on 8.0

`add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("Banners125");'));`

Any suggestion on how i can fix this code in my wordpress theme for php 8.0?

I would like it to work on php 8.0

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Comment: see how create_function(''",..) has to be modify:       I just figured out why it crashes on 8.0. Open the file dcwp_jquery_accordion.php in the plugin folder. Go to line 63 and comment out or remove,   https://wordpress.org/support/topic/crash-with-php-8-0/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP 7.2 Function create\_function() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161526/php-7-2-function-create-function-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`create_function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) was deprecated in 7.2 and removed in 8.0. Your code can be rewritten in several ways, one of which is:

```php
add_action(
    'widgets_init',
    function() {
        return register_widget("Banners125");
    }
);
```

Comment: If this code has been working for a “long time”, I wouldn’t be surprised if you have old-style constructors, too, which was common with widgets.