# How to solve this almost easy create_function for PHP?

Tags: php

How do I convert another create_function. The one below

```
return create_function('$f,$e=null', "return ($parsed_tpl);");
```

to

```
$e=null;
return function($f,$e) { return ($parsed_tpl); };
```

or

```
return function($f,$e=null;) { return ($parsed_tpl); };
```

But neither of them are working.

I have tried everything above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP 7.2 Function create\_function() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161526/php-7-2-function-create-function-is-deprecated). That answer shows the `use` part which you are missing

Comment: @ChrisHaas The `use` statement is not the only problem here; the original function is using the fact that create_function was eval in disguise: https://3v4l.org/Y5Dib#v7.1.21

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Answer (score 0):

The key part to notice on the original code is this:

```
"return ($parsed_tpl);"
```

Note the double-quotes, meaning the variable will be expanded in the string *before* passing it to `create_function`. Then the *expanded* form will form the body of the function.

In other words, the actual code of the created function will be completely different every time - it won't just *return* the string, it will *execute it as PHP code*.

To achieve the same effect in current PHP, you need to use the [eval](https://php.net/eval) function:

```
return eval("return ($parsed_tpl);");
```

You also have two mistakes in your attempt:

- `$e=null` isn't an assignment, it's a default value for the parameter; it doesn't need a semicolon
- You have to "capture" the `$parsed_tpl` variable with the `use` keyword to use it inside the function

The format is this:

```
$my_anonymous_function = 
    function($some_param, $next_param='default value', $another='another default')
    use ($something_captured, $something_else) {
        /* body of function using those 5 variables*/
    };
```